# Java @Column-Annotation change the name of columns in Code

Tags: java, database, oracle, jpa, annotations

I have an Entity-Class (@Entity) where I have specified Columns(@Column) for OracleDB. It is possible to change the names of columns in code? And has it any affects to the existing database? Because the database contains actually lot of data.

I can't test it by myself now, because I do not have access to database actually.

Can anyone help me resp. can you give me some tips where can I search for a answer for my question?

Entity-Class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Example {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private long id;
 @Column
 private String firstName;
 @Column
 private Date dateTime;

 //Setter / Getter
}
```

Comment: What does "name of column in code" mean?

Comment: You can do `@Column(name = "name_you_want")` is this what you're asking?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I want to change the column-names in OracleDB over the Java-Code? It is possible? @

Comment: You want to alter column name. right?

Answer (score 1):

If column in you db is as

```
@Column(name = "name_you_have_in_db")
```

If you will do

```
@Column(name="name_you_want")
```

then it is not possible because I guess hibernate doesn't track renames. It will create new field into the DB.

So solution is stop your app, alter your table and start your app again.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted to hear :)